# Processing in Xcode

Tags: xcode, user-interface, processing

I created an application/sketch via Processing. But now I want to add a user interface around it (not the processing ui's). Whats the best way to to this? I was thinking of creating an application in Xcode and somehow running my processing sketch or application in my Xcode application. Is there anyway to do this/ what is the best way/ should i try something besides xcode? I can export my sketch as .pde or .java. Basically it would be ideal to combine parts of Processing to a better UI builder such as Xcode.

Comment: Huh, do you want to write AppKit code and run on an AVR or what?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few Processing GUI libraries like [ControlP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/) out there and you can always use Java's [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) components from Processing if you want closer to native controls (with the native look & feel).

If you prefer using native components it might be simpler to port your Processing code to [openFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc), a project similar to and inspired by Processing. You might also want to have a look at the [ofxNativeGUI addon](https://github.com/ofZach/ofxNativeGui)

[image: ofxNativeGUI]